# Div with a scrollbar, with sticky div on top and bottom

Tags: css

I want to have a container with a scrollbar, with a *sticky* div on top and bottom. **How to achieve that sticky div behaviour?**
i.e. with the following code, the yellow and red div should be always visible.

(Note: The scrollbar should be full height, i.e. close to #top and #footer as well, not restricted to #main).

```css
#top { background-color: yellow; }
#footer { background-color: red; }
#container { overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">STICKY ON TOP1<br>STICKY ON TOP2</div>
  <div id="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="footer">STICKY ON BOTTOM1<br>STICKY ON BOTTOM2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I made 2 Plunkers:

[**PLUNKER 1**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUf1JryzNhWamR9RZyor?p=preview) Is just a slightly improved version of the **Snippet** below. The biggest difference between [**PLUNKER 1**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUf1JryzNhWamR9RZyor?p=preview) and [**PLUNKER 2**](http://plnkr.co/edit/k8Do8hu0I5ngrMi14fm3?p=preview) is that the latter contains an iframe in which the `#main` (the scrolling content) resides within.

The key components that both Plunkers share are:

- `#header`, `#footer`, and `#main` are `position: absolute`
- `#container` is `position: fixed`

Some notable differences:

- Version 1 needs actual `<br/>` within the `#main` in order to view the very bottom. `padding` and `margins` do not help with this like I expected.
- Version 2 on the other hand can use `padding`, `margins`, and `<br/>` within `#main`. This I didn't expect because `#main` is within an iframe, so I expected some limitations.
- The weirdest discovery is that `#container` is not affected by width changes in version 1, I think I'm missing something obvious...
- Whilst version 2 can be re-sized and still maintain desired scrolling behavior (that was expected).
- BTW, `floats` are old and fragile, you want to avoid them if at all possible. If you use a `position:absolute` layout and still want to use `floats`, read this article on [`floats`](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and this article on [**`faux absolute positioning`**](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxabsolutepositioning).

[**PLUNKER 1**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUf1JryzNhWamR9RZyor?p=preview)

[**PLUNKER 2**](http://plnkr.co/edit/k8Do8hu0I5ngrMi14fm3?p=preview)

---

#### OLD

You mean like this?

```css
#top { background-color: yellow; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left:0; z-index: 1; width: 100%; height: 40px; }
#footer { background-color: red; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; left:0; z-index: 1; width: 100%;height: 40px; }
#container { overflow-y: scroll; height: 100vh; position: relative; }
#main { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 1000px; padding: 50px 40px 50px 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="embed">
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">STICKY ON TOP1<br>STICKY ON TOP2</div>
  <div id="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="footer">STICKY ON BOTTOM1<br>STICKY ON BOTTOM2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, except that 1) When scrollbar is 100% up, the top text is cropped  2) if this whole thing is embedded in another `<div>`, the `position: fixed` will cause an issue. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: I think 1) is taken care of with padding, but I'm not sure about  2)...see update.

Comment: About 2), if #embed is moved somewhere else (e.g. on float:right, with 50% width), will the "fixed" items follow?

Comment: No, it'll stay true to the viewport, unfortunately. The only thing float has an advantage over position is you can have text wrap around a floated element which looks nice if you have a newspaper column layout. You could try an iframe with sticky header/footer, If you haven't found a solution after I get back from work, I'll see if I can.